# Why does this function recur forever?

Tags: recursion, infinite-loop, project-euler

I am trying to solve [Project Euler Problem 31](https://projecteuler.net/problem=31), but I don't want answers for that. I just want to know why this function recurs forever. It just keeps subtracting one forever, on the ones where it goes too far. I want it to stop as soon as it goes to far (getting a negative number reveals that that happened), but this code doesn't seem to work:

```
coins = {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200};

CoinSum[0, __] = 1;
CoinSum[g_, __] := 0 /; g < 0;
CoinSum[g_, n_] := Module[{i = Select[coins, # <= n &]},
  Total[CoinSum[g - #, #] & /@ i]]
```

In the preceding code, `g` means the goal that my function is trying to reach, and `n` is the largest size of coin that it can use. To (hypothetically) run it to solve the Project Euler problem, you could use it like this: `CoinSum[200,200]`.

Comment: Your code works OK,but it is slow. Try it in a fresh kernel. `CoinSum[10, 200]`

Comment: What's the starting condition? (i.e. what do you evaluate? `CoinSum[ ? ]`) Or, what are `n` and `g` supposed to represent?

Comment: Don't read ahead .... SPOILER ...  .... SPOILER ... FrobeniusSolve[coins, 10] // Length

Comment: Thank you, @Dr.belisarius, Turns out I just needed to restart the Kernel.